# Radiobutton Java retrieve selected button

Tags: button, radio-button, radio-group

im having a problem in set selected of radio button. What i need is when a person edit his profile,he will be able to see his previous selection of the radio button. The variable name of the button group is "payment".

This is one of the code in my class:

```
 if(visaBtn.isSelected()){
        creditCardType = "VISA";}
    if(mastercardBtn.isSelected()){
        creditCardType = "MASTERCARD";}
    if(amexBtn.isSelected()){
        creditCardType = "AMERICA EXPRESS";}
    if(noneBtn.isSelected()){
        creditCardType = "NONE";}
```

This is my other code for retrieving the selected item in my other class but not working:
payment.isSelected(user.getcCardType());

Answer (score 0):

try changing the

if..if..if..if

to

if..else if..else if..else....

this will create a chain of solutions to go through

You are saying if a certain situation happens without a way to back it up when you use only ifs.
When you use if/else if/else, you are saying "if the first doesn't work, check 2, and if not 2, then it must be 3, so use that!"

Hope that helps

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution but what i meant was how to get the radiobutton selected when i retrive it instead of the text

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you explain it to me as to what you;re doing? Are you trying to get the text to show when pressing the radio button?

Comment: im able to get the text.What i meant was when a user decide to update its account, it is reflected that the radio button should be checked in his account

Comment: So what you're trying to do is update the radio button if the user updates the account?

Comment: Yes,thats what i mean.The problem that im facing now is, when the user edit his account,he is unable to see its previously checked radio button.

Comment: Well, the only thing I could maybe say is create a bool value for each radio button. When youre in your if statements, if(noneButton.isSelected()) /*bool value*/nonePressed = true; Then later on in the program do if(nonePressed) {//set the noneButton to be the initial radio button pressed when the user updates the account} does that help any?